# Verificar si dos secuencias son complementarias

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear y ejecutar un comando, se deben ingresar y comparar dos secuencias y ver si son complementarias, el ejercicio es el siguiente:

Complementarias (secuencia1, secuencia2): esta función recibe dos secuencias y devuelve verdadero si una cadena es complementaria a la otra para cada una de las posiciones hasta la secuencia de menor largo o falso en otro caso. Es decir:

- Si en la secuencia 1 hay A, en secuencia 2 debe haber T en esa misma posición
- Si en la secuencia 1 hay T en secuencia 2 debe haber A
- Si en la secuencia 1 hay C en secuencia 2 debe haber G
- Si en la secuencia 1 hay G en secuencia 2 debe haber C
- Si hay N, se ignora esa posición

Por ejemplo: recibe "ANATATC", "TATATAGGT", retorna: true.

Esto es lo que pude hacer:

```
sec1 = input("Ingrese una secuencia: ")
sec2 = input("Ingrese una secuencia: ")

def funComplemento(sec1,sec2):
  complementoFun = False
  for base in complementoFun:

    [A=T]
    if base == "A": 
    for base in sec2:
      if base =="T"
      return True

      complementoFun += "T"
    elif base == "T":
      complementoFun += "A"
    elif base == "C":
      complementoFun += "G"
    elif base == "G":
      complementoFun += "C"
  return complementoFun
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sec1 = "ANATATC"
sec2 = "TATATAGGT"

def funComplemento( sec1, sec2 ):
    for i in range( len( sec1 )):
        if sec1[ i ] == "A" and ( i >= len( sec2 ) or sec2[i] != "T" ) : 
            return False
        elif sec1[ i ] == "T" and not sec2.__contains__( "A" ):
            return False
        elif sec1[ i ] == "C" and not sec2.__contains__( "G" ):
            return False
        elif sec1[ i ] == "G" and not sec2.__contains__( "C" ):
            return False    
  return True
  
print( funComplemento( sec1, sec2 ))
```

Como verás, simplifiqué el enfoque, para tener una función más "limpia".
Con el `for` recorremos la primer cadena.
El primer `if`, es el que merece un poco de atención, primero verificamos que la letra contenida en la posición de **sec1**, sobre la cual estamos iterando, contenga una "A", concatenamos esta condición (mediante `and`) con un grupo de condiciones, que evalúa si la posición actual excede el tamaño de **sec2**, en cuyo caso devuelve `true`, y sino verifica que sec2 en esa posición no contenga una "T".
Verificar que **`i`** no sobrepase el tamaño de **sec2** solo tiene sentido si existe la posibilidad de que **sec2** sea más corta que **sec1**, en cuyo caso, si la posición de "A" estubiese fuera del rango, intentar **sec[ i ]** nos arrojaría un error.
Las siguientes comprobaciones son triviales, solo se verifica que si en **sec1** está tal letra, **sec2** contenga tal otra.
Si el ciclo del `for` se completa, se retorna un true.